# Entityframework core query related data filtering

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following model

Deal.cs

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public double? Price { get; set; }

public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public User User { get; set; }
```

User.cs

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string ResumptionCookie { get; set; }
public List<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
```

I'm trying to **get all users who currently have a deal with a specific code**. I could do a get all users and write a big LINQ query but there must a more elegant way.

I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) but it's not quite what I'm looking for and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: what about using : `db.Users.Where(x=>x.Deals.Any(y=>y.Code == "your_givenCode"));`

Comment: Ah yes, this returns an IEnumerable<Users> but is this optimized as far as EntityFramework is concerned? I was thinking I'd need to use the `.Include` or `.Collections`. I'm probably over optimizing here, but I'd like to avoid loading all the data in memory and filtering it aftewards.

Comment: Above code is lazy loading i.e. loads when the query materialize like with using ToList(), First(), Count() and other methods. But I suspect, whether lazy loading is supported in EF core or not.

Comment: According to the docs, lazy loading isn't supported in EF core right now
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/index

Comment: You're too much focused at loading. You don't need to load one single `Deal` for this query. Akash's query does exactly what you prescribe.

Answer (score 0):

you can try filtering on the deals first then selecting the user

```
db.Deals.Where(x=>x.code == "specified code").Select(x=>x.User)
```

assuming that each user has the deal with "specified code" once
if not use .Distenct() 
or what Akash KC suggested in the comments

Comment: The problem is that EF Core doesn't support lazy loading yet. I still can't figure out how to achieve this by some other means.

Comment: Try adding .Include(x=>x.User) before the .Where condition